# Yii2 Upload image file dont save the file, but I see the post data OK

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2, image-uploading

I have the next form:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-profile-edit', 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
     <?= Html::activeFileInput($model, 'image_upload', ['class' => 'hidden', 'id' => 'file-avatar', 'accept' => 'image/*', 'onchange' => 'javascript:this.form.submit()'])?>
<?php ActiveForm::end();
```

This rules in the model:

```
['image-upload', 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'], 'maxSize' => 45000],
[['image-upload'], 'safe'],
```

And this code in the controller:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image_upload');
            if ($file) {
                //print_r($_FILES);
                echo "<br>pathactual: " . getcwd();
                echo "<br>basename: " . $file->baseName;
                echo "<br>extension: " . $file->extension;
                echo "<br>name: " . $file->name;
                echo "<br>SaveUrl: " . Yii::$app->homeUrl . "assets/avatars/" . $file->baseName . "." . $file->extension;
                echo "<br>Error: " . $file->error; //This shows 0
                echo "Size: " . $file->size;

                $model->avatar = $file->baseName. "-big." . $file->extension;

                if($model->update(true, ["avatar"])){
                    echo "<br>avatar actualizado";
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('profile-Msg-OK', Yii::t("app", "Generic_Changes_OK"));
                    //Guardamos el fichero del avatar
                    if($file->saveAs(Yii::$app->homeUrl . "assets/avatars/" . $file->baseName . "-big." . $file->extension)){
                        echo "<br>Imagen guardada correctamente.";
                    }else{
                        echo "<br>Imagen no guardada correctamente: " . $file->error; //This shows 1

                    }
             }

}
```

I can see the $file object correct, size, tempName, baseName, extension.. I save the avatar name in $model->avatar and then I make the update. This works fine.

Now, I execute the saveAs method but always enters in else, the $file->errror value in this moment is 1. I see the UploadedFile documentation and see:

> $error    integer An error code describing the status of this file
>   uploading.

Search the possible status [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) and I see that 1 corresponds to:

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Then, I go to my php.ini file (I revised it from phpinfo) I have 40M

> upload_max_filesize   40M 40M

The files what I am using to test have 14 and 16 KB.
Any idea about this?

If anybody need more info, please comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct the saving path

```
if($file->saveAs(Yii::$app->homeUrl . "assets/avatars/" . $file->baseName . "-big." . $file->extension))
```

here

```
Yii::$app->homeUrl
```

is not what you want ,because its a url of your application, you need something like

```
if($file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . "/assets/avatars/" . $file->baseName . "-big." . $file->extension))
```

an absolute path in filesystem

Comment: Thanks! I also tried with getcwd() without success, this works great for me :) I was becoming crazy.